# What's the difference between these two Venn diagrams?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I want to describe these two representations, what should I say about the first and what about the second one?

[image: Venn diagrams]

My idea is that the first a three separate sets and the third one is the union, is it right?

Comment: I don't understand what your diagrams mean.  What's a "representation" ?  What does it mean when you put a letter inside a circle?  What does it mean when you put a letter outside a circle?

Comment: You seem to be using the letters $A$, $B$, $C$, etc. for several different things at once! Do you mean that you have 5 sets, $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, that $A$ contains elements $b,c,d$; $B$ contains elements $a,d,e$, etc., and you are trying to make a Venn diagram of this? Of something else?

Comment: I think @Arturo has the right idea. If the letters in the first diagram were relabelled $A',B',C'$, etc. then they would be five subsets of $\{A,B,C,D,E\}$, and the picture on the right is sort of a spatial depiction of how these sets overlap. OP asking us what he "should" say about them is a vague question still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphs are identical. The first diagram shows inclusion of the elements without visual representation of the mutually inclusive elements of the sets.  The second diagram shows an overlapping Venn Diagram.

Comment: Is is there any maths notation for the first one and the second one?

Comment: None that I know off.  It's just difference in visual representation.